# Spring Cloud Config Server - Placeholder Label

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config

I have developed a microservice using Spring Boot. This service is fetching the properties using Spring cloud config server. This microservice accepts version in the header and based on version , it executes the appropriate function. In my github repo , I have 2 branches , 1 for each version. The service usually sends the below information to config server to fetch the properties -

application-name + profile + label

Is there a way to have a placeholder in place of label in my .yml file? I want the label to be set to v1 dynamically , if I see v1 in the header else v2.

**EDIT:**

I see references to placeholder in this documentation (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html) under section "Placeholders in Git URI", however I am not sure how values can be substituted dynamically from incoming request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

spring-cloud-config-server makes several REST API available, allowing to query directly for a property file:

```
$ hostname:port/{label}/{name}-{profiles}.properties]
```

You can dynamically use any label of your choice, as long as it matches an existing label on git.

For instance, to retrieve `application.properties`, labeled `v1` in git:

```
 $ http://${hostname}:${port}/v1/application.properties
```

**Config-server REST API:**

- /{name}/{profiles}/{label:.*
- /{label}/{name}-{profiles}.properties
- /{name}-{profiles}.json
- /{label}/{name}-{profiles}.json
- /{label}/{name}-{profiles}.yml
- /{label}/{name}-{profiles}.yaml
- /{name}-{profiles}.yml
- /{name}-{profiles}.yaml
- /{name}/{profiles:.*[^-].*}
- /{name}-{profiles}.properties
- /{name}/{profile}/{label}/**

---

I tried a sample `spring-cloud-server` project with a property file on a git. I applied the git tags `v1` and `v2` with different values in the file for each label (I used the profile `remote`):

**label v1**:

```
http://localhost:8888/v1/application-remote.properties
> testproperty: remotevalue-v1
```

**label v2**:

```
http://localhost:8888/v2/application-remote.properties
> testproperty: remotevalue-v2
```

**no label**:

```
http://localhost:8888/application-remote.properties
> testproperty: remotevalue-master
```

---

**Java code**

I did not try it, but I suppose you could also use cloud-config-server's java API (injecting and calling the controller directly instead of doing an http request):

```
@Autowired
EnvironmentController environmentController;
...

Environment labelled = environmentController.labelled("application", "remote", "v1");
Map<?, ?> keyValues = labelled.getPropertySources().get(0).getSource();
```